# How to calculate concentration of a protein based on known concentration and mw of other protein

Tags: solubility, concentration, proteins

I have a Peptide A (mw = 5074Da), the table below showed
measured concentration by [Qubit](https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/Q33211) from 5uM up to 80uM solution.
All under 20uL solution.

[image]

Below is the standard plot for Peptide A (not sure if it's relevant or not):

[image]

Let's say I have another Peptide B (mw = 3102Da),
how can we calculate the *expected* [Qubit](https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/Q33211) read of Peptide B  based on Peptide A (just by calculation)?

For example just for 1 node: 20uM.

Comment: It does not seem to me to be linear.

Comment: @Poutnik Sorry do you mean it can't be calculated?

Comment: I mean there is consistent bending down and that questions justification of linear approximation.

Comment: @Poutnik If we ignore the *linearity* issue you brought up, how can my question be answered?

Comment: I was not going to address the question itself and I would let it on users involved in this area. But, I have noticed the question is very laconic in description and elaboration and has lack of signs of explicit own solving effort. It would not please users much.

Comment: What is "nodes"? Please add some clarification on the concentration units, as these are orders of magnitude different (measured vs nominal). If you read the manual you'll see that the measured concentration can vary ~12% between *proteins*, but this will apply to peptides only if the functional principle of the assay still applies. I would think it's ok.

Comment: https://www.science.smith.edu/cmbs/wp-content/uploads/sites/36/2015/09/Qubit-Protein-Assay.pdf

Comment: @BuckThorn Thanks so much for your reply. *Nodes* is the concentration in the peptide solution I put in the tube (before adding the working solution) to be measured with Qubit.

Comment: It would appear that the signal from the instrument is roughly proportional to the mass of peptide, although your other question shows this is not a simple linear relation, which explains your question. However, you may want to edit this post to make such details more clear. Also, is "nodes" common nomenclature in your lab? A node is a connection in my understanding.

Answer (score 4):

If knowing the concentration of peptide B is important and you have pure peptide B available, you should measure standards of known concentrations of peptide B in the assay.

The assay works through a dye that has little fluorescence in solution and a lot when bound to proteins. The mechanism of binding is not known or not divulged. While there is a claim that there is little variation of mass of protein sample vs. fluorescence signal, the data presented by the company uses larger globular proteins.

We don't know what the amino acid composition or the structure of your peptides are. We also don't know whether the assay works under native or denaturing conditions (the assay buffer has a pH between 6 and 8, but there is no information about its composition).

If knowing the concentration of peptide B is not so important, you could assume that the same mass of peptide will have the same fluorescent signal. Or you could use the assay to get a relative concentration if the absolute concentration is unimportant.